# Absolute position within IE6 & IE7 not working properly

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a quickly put together site for a friend showing them absolute positioned within a relative positioned div.

I've checked it in most browsers through Browserlabs and all work but IE6 & IE7.

What I've looked for out here isn't fixing my issue although I've tried multiple methods.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jmcintosh.aisites.com/tara/index.html

Comment: [It's time for IE6 to die.](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)

Comment: Agree with @samold - Jason, you should help IE6 die its natural death by intentionally *not* supporting it.

Comment: @StephenP: Sadly, people still use it. You can make a flashing black and white banner on your site, though, that will follow the mouse around for only IE6 users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try displaying your images as `block` elements:

```
img {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: That fixed my spacing issue but IE6 pushes the div way farther to the left than it should.

Comment: Instead of having a shoes DIV, try making it just a single `<img>` tag without the wrapping `<div>`.

Comment: @ScottSimpson: You're dealing with IE6 here. Sanity and logic do not apply.

Comment: it should be display: inline-block;

Comment: Keeping it in a div AND adding display:block fixes my spacing issue. However, IE6 pushes my image much farther to the right than IE7. Man, this is dumb. :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: `inline-block` isn't supported on any IE except IE9.

Comment: @Jason: Try a conditional stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but notice you're missing the browser compatability method in your css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
```

I can't say if this well fix your problem, but if it doesn't it should towards other problems occurring.